# Android emulator crashes on launch

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hello everyone :) I decided to try out Android SDK with NetBeans. I installed SDK and packages, created ADV, installed plugin for NetBeans. I've writen small app, then launched it. At first it did not show up. I launched again and my antivirus asked for net access, which I kindly alowed. Then the device showed black screen and I closed the window, while my NetBeans window did not update at all (like the emulator was still running). Next runs were just popping new proccesses up in Task Manager and instantly getting out of there. Running the emulator straight from the SDK Manager just returned emulator-arm.exe not responding window. My verbose run gave this:

```
emulator: found SDK root at D:\Programming\Android SDK
emulator: Android virtual device file at: C:\Users\Teodor\.android/avd/AVD16.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 16
emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: D:\Programming\Android SDK/platforms\android-16\skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir D:\Programming\Android SDK/platforms\android-16\skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: D:\Programming\Android SDK/platforms\android-16\skins/WVGA800/hardware.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\Teodor\.android\default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file 'D:\Programming\Android SDK/platforms\android-16\skins/WVGA800/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = arm
  hw.cpu.model = cortex-a8
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 200m
  disk.dataPartition.path = C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = AVD16
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-arm.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-arm.exe -android-hw C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xc800000,initfile=D:\Programming\Android SDK/system-images\android-16\armeabi-v7a\/system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to C:\Users\Teodor\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMPD8B6.tmp
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\Teodor\.android\avd\AVD16.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
Failed to allocate memory: 1455

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I am blaming the fact that I did not wait until my firs run showed ANDROID letters. So right now I don't know what to do... Reinstalling everything (my internet connection will take a LONG time to do that) or is there a better solution?

P.S. I tried removing and adding the virtual device

**EDIT:** Killing the adb.exe in Task Manager running from SYSTEM did not help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find Eclipse more convenient than Net Beans for android application development. If you can reconsider the option of using Development Tool than I would say Eclipse is a better option.

Comment: Should it be fine if I have both, Eclipse and Net Beans at the same pc? Or should I remove NB for it not to conflict?

Comment: No I have Net Beans and Eclipse installed in my PC. I am using both for java programs but I am using only Eclipse for android cant say why but I find it convenient.

Comment: Well, I guess cause it works with Eclipse and not with NetBeans.. I will try that now.

Comment: @Dibya: because it is recommended by Google.

Answer (score 2):

One of the first things you'll need to learn about Android dev is reading actually reading the logs and googling for the error. Have you tried the solutions provided in different forums when searching for

```
android emulator Failed to allocate memory: 1455
```

Anyway, you'll want to test your stuff on a real device sooner or later, save yourself a lot of frustration with the emulator and get a cheap android phone.